# Copying blob fields in Scriptella

Tags: scriptella

I'm using **Scriptella** for database migration.
What would be the best approach to copy a longblob field from table A to table B ?

When I do this job like this:

```
<query ...
  SELECT FL_DATA as data FROM A where FL_DATA IS NOT NULL
  <script ...>
    INSERT B (FL_DATA) VALUES ('$data');
  </script>
</query>
```

then it will just write 'BLOB: java.io.IOException: Content too long to fit in memory' into the destination field (btw: the size of the longblob is just a few kBytes).

Answer (score 0):

When $variable syntax is used, a text value of the variable is simply inserted into statement's text. A recommended approach would be to use prepared statements syntax. In this case  values will be transferred separately from the SQL statement.  Please try the following:

```
<query ...
  SELECT FL_DATA as data FROM A where FL_DATA IS NOT NULL
  <script ...>
    INSERT B (FL_DATA) VALUES (?data);
  </script>
</query>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this is not a answer, but I don't how to comment ejboy's answer.

Ejboy, it doesn't work for me. I've tried prepared statement with (in my case) ?description and ?2. The same error I get when I try to show the content on the console:

```
<query connection-id="database">
    SELECT id, description FROM table;
    <script connection-id="copy_database">
        INSERT INTO table VALUES (?1, ?2);
    </script>
    <script connection-id="text">
      $id, $description
    </script>
</query>
```

I get the same error for both, for showing and inserting (here example for showing):

```
BRA0735401, CLOB: java.io.IOException: Content too long to fit in memory
```

My main task to make a copy from one database to another. Like in Jan's case the blob/clob content is about 40 kB (a list of key/value, each in the separate line, from database point of view this is MySQL MEDIUMTEXT).I know, that is possible to insert a blob/clob from a file (scriptella example with mp3 files), and it's possible to write content of a blob to a file (scriptella example with odbc and pictures with janino), so I will to try to use a solution with a temporary file, but it's not a beautiful solution. Am I right?

Is there any simpler solution?

Regards,
Jacek

Comment: The error is printed if message exceeds 10MB, please check what kind of data you are outputting. The easiest solution would be not to output BLOB content to the console. Alternatively you can truncate the description using substr or another SQL function, e.g. `SELECT ID, DESCRIPTION, SUBSTR(DESCRIPTION,1, 100) as SHORT_DESC FROM ...` and the print it using $SHORT_DESC

Comment: I think the problem is with scriptella.jdbc.Lobs.ReadonlyClob.toString() method. This method is described as "For debug purposes" but is used in scriptella. I have remove in this method "CLOB: " string at the beginning and the second parameter "1024" of the call of IOUtils.toString and now everything works fine!.

Comment: I've created a [ticket](http://javaforge.com/issue/54430) to track this issue. But in any case I advise not to use BLOB or CLOB fields in $expressions. This may degrade performance or cause OutOfMemoryErrors on larger datasets.

Comment: Thank you for your replay. $expression on CLOB I've used only in developing time. The task is to move some records (with CLOB field) older than e.g. 30 days from main to an archive database. Without $expression, before I've changed the toString() function, I've had the same problem. I've just read the ticket. You want to increase the amount of data to 10k. How can I make such described in my comment operation, when CLOB field is greater than 10k?

Comment: Why can't you simply transfer without using "text" driver, i.e.
<query connection-id="database">

    SELECT id, description FROM table; <!-- Put validity criteria here -->
    <script connection-id="copy_database">
        INSERT INTO table VALUES (?1, ?2);
    </script>

?